# How to install Xcode 7 beta on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I need to make installation of Xcode 7 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

I can't update an operating system above version 10.10.3 because on a notebook Hackintosh is installed. And it isn't updated correctly unfortunately.

I know that it is impossible to install the final Xcode 7 version on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.

But it can be possible to install the beta version?

What maximum beta version Xcode 7 can be installed on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **No**.

But over the years I have built a lot of hackintoshes and will be quiet happy to help you debug yours, I personally use a hackintosh 10.10.5 on a AMD build and use Xcode 7.1 to learn swift.
Well if there is hope, you can try messing around with the `info.plist` and see if that helps.

Try changing:

```
minimumOSVersion         10.10.5
```

to

```
minimumOSVersion         10.10.1
```

Comment: I was able to successfully install Xcode version 7 beta (7A120f) [PRE-RELEASE]. See this blog post http://devtype.blogspot.com/2015/10/Kak-ustanovit-Xcode-7-na-Mac-OS-X-Yosemite-10-10-3.html